# Condição se conteúdo da combobox for selecionado, carrega os campos

Tags: typescript

Bom dia Galera,

Estou com a seguinte dificuldade em typescript,

Quero selecionar um campo de um combobox, quando eu selecionar esse campo, quero que carregue determinados campos... O problema é que deve ser feito em TypeScript e eu não consigo achar conteúdos para fazê-lo, peço desculpas por não colocar nenhum exemplo, mas não encontrei... se tiver algum site bom sobre Typescript fora o typescriptlang.org, agradeço!!!!

Comment: Não entendi bem o que quer. É fazer um AJAX para receber os valores do campo? Ou só tornar o que já está lá visível? Seja como for a resposta é que deve procurar como fazer em JavaScript. Qualquer código JS será perfeitamente válido em TS.

Comment: Typescript é só um superset de javascript. Para o que quer fazer, o código vai ser exatamente igual ao escrito em javascript, não faz sentido procurar por material específico para typescript. Veja como fazer o mesmo em JS.

Comment: Obrigado @GuilhermeBernal, achei que TypeScript era outra coisa... Vlw mesmo!